# How to load the API data to react component once the promise is resolved?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, codemirror

I am trying to create a simple app that calls **Github API** to get a file and display that file in a `CodeMirror` Component. The code is given below. However, currently, even though I can log the file in the console, I am unable to load the file in the `CodeMirror` component. It only displays `[object Promise]`.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import CodeMirror from 'react-codemirror'
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');
require('codemirror/lib/codemirror.css');
var axios = require('axios');

var App = createReactClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        code: getRepos(),

    };
},
updateCode: function(newCode) {
    this.setState({
        code: newCode,
    });
},
render: function() {
    var options = {
        lineNumbers: true,
        styleSelectedText: true,
    };

    return <CodeMirror value={this.state.code.toString()} onChange={this.updateCode} options={options} />
}
});


async function getRepos(){

var code = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/repos/<.java file>',
    {headers: {
            "Accept" : "application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw"
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        var codeq = response.data;
        return codeq;
    });

    console.log(code);
    return code;

}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

What should I do to get the resolved promise to my CodeMirror component?. 
 p.s I am very new to React.

Comment: Sorry we couldn’t help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not calling it properly. You need to call `getRepos()` inside `componentDidMount` function like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  getRepos().then((res) => this.setState({code: res}))
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This, in fact, updates the state of the 'code' but the only problem is that even though the render function is called again it does not update/render the file with the new state of the 'code' in the CodeMirror component. It still shows [Object promise] even after `componentDidMount` is called.

Comment: That's weird. Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/advg98rx/
And this function doesn't have to be async. But if it's async it should work too.